# AVQueuePlayer play but no sound

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)playVideoInteractionNarration:(NSString *)vNarr{

[self pauseActionExecution];

NSURL *u = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:vNarr];
AVQueuePlayer *player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithURL:u];
self.controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls=NO;

[controller.player setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(videoNarrationFinishedPlaying:)                                                 
 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
 object:player.currentItem];
//NSLog(@"MPVIDEOOOOOOO %@", player);

[controller.player setVolume:1.0];
[controller.player setMuted:NO];
[controller setViewInCurrentController];
[controller.player play];

}

- (void)videoNarrationFinishedPlaying:(NSNotification *) aNotification{

AVPlayerItem * item = [aNotification object];

[self.controller removeViewInCurrentController];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                              object:item];

[self.controller.player pause];
[self.controller release];
[self playActionExecution];
}
```

the video start and finish correctly but NO sound 
why ?

Comment: are you testing is application in device or simulator ?

Comment: no on the device ...

Comment: Is there device vibrate mode ? or in sound then increase your default sound

Comment: no it is not in vibrate mode the sound is at maximum

Comment: why -1 i don't understand !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right answer is this:

```
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@import AVKit;
@import AVFoundation;
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer; 



NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];
  self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
  self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

  AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
  videoLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
  videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];

  [self.avPlayer play];
```

**Try this code and comment your one and check that in your device did sound work or not ?**

Comment: i had to change a bit the code because i haven't   [self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];

Comment: @T-student try this code with your simulator and check this in different device

Comment: but i used     self.controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = self.avPlayer;     [self.controller setViewInCurrentController];
instead of [self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer]

Comment: @T-student did you want to play a video to your fix size of you in your controller or display in full screen ?

Comment: in full screen, but the app is pretty complicated i haven't a view where i play the video so i can't do [self.view ... ] i haven't this.

Comment: in my case self.view is my whole controller's view and i just add new view that my videoLayer so its display in full screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126400/discussion-between-t-student-and-himanshu-moradiya).

Comment: on the simulator i listen all... on the iPhone no... why?

Comment: the iPhone has ios9.2

Comment: @T-student did you try some other application sound in your same device ? and its play sound

Comment: your answer is worng ! i already answerd by myself. thank you

Comment: i don't know why you added -1 to my question !

Comment: @T-student i did not give you mines vote its given by some one else