# How to get or streamed video file from cloudinary which are already uploaded ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video

I have uploaded video on cloudinary Account succesfully, then cloudinary account provided url of uploaded video. I want to play and streamed that cloudinary url in Avplayer. So that I can watch full video.
uploaded video url provided by cloudinary as below-
"http://res.cloudinary.com/dep7kjzyg/video/upload/v1484562338/jol8unlgazw0awwhaidf.mov"

I have tried following code but cant play in Avplayer ios

```
 NSString *urlString = @"http://res.cloudinary.com/dep7kjzyg/video/upload/v1484562338/jol8unlgazw0awwhaidf.mov";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            self.item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
            self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:self.item];
            AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoFinished:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.item];
            playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        playerLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
        [self.player play];
        self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40192431/6656894 refer this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"your string"]
if (URL)
{
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:URL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    [player play];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```